# React Native: Getting 68 facial landmarks?

Tags: react-native, image-processing, expo

So I'm attempting to get facial landmarks using React Native (expo or not, it really doesn't matter) and I'm trying to get all 68 landmarks like you can in [dlib](http://dlib.net/), however, [expo doesn't seem to support that](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facedetector/) and I can't find a package for dlib that works with React-Native (unless I'm missing something?).

I'm well aware of [fast-face android](https://github.com/gicheonkang/fast-face-android), and I'm looking for something similar to that. Alas, getting the "general" coords of facial landmarks doesn't cut it, and I need all 68 and I honestly can't find anything.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The quick guide: use facebit.net service. Disclaimer: I'm the author of facebit.net :D

Comment: @thachnb thanks for the tip, but I'm looking for something offline. But I'll definitely look into it!